# Creating Action in Qgis

Tags: qgis, python, actions

I'm trying to create an action in QGIS that open this link

> htt p://www.gulliver.it/itinerario-foto/14451/#!/uploaded/2014/large/20140929123749.jpg||grid2

but the character `|` is converted into `%7C` preventing the page beeing open correctly, in Chrome, indeed the result of the action `[% "web-link field" %]` is:

> htt p://www.gulliver.it/itinerario-foto/14451/#!/uploaded/2014/large/20140929123749.jpg%7C%7Cgrid2

I defined action as you can see in the picture
[image: qggis actions' definitions]

Here there are the webpages as they appear in my browser:
[image]
Rewriting the link in the field and the action like:  `[% "truncated web-link field" %]||grid2` is the same.

How is it possible to make the page open correctly?

---

Alternatively I could open the webpage internally but, following this instructions

> ht tps://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html#hard-fa-open-a-webpage-directly-in-qgis
>   ,

I haven't any results (nothing happens clicking on elements).

Any solutions?

Comment: i tried your links (both links) and everything is running fine here ... using qgis 2.18.7 ... don't u forget something ? Can u show us how u defined the action (screen capture ?)

Comment: To enable the actions u have to have both the **"action button"** and the right layer selected ... did u check that ?

Comment: The first and the second actions badly work, because I don't get the webpage-link properly, but in the browser address bar it appears  the link ending with "...%7C%7Cgrid2", which doesn't return the original layout, in my chrome browser

Comment: So the action is working a bit then ? u said "nothing happens when clicking  on elements" ... r u sure of the url construction and r u sure of the **grid2** parameter ? When i try your url i have a grid of pictures indeed ....

Comment: The first and the second actions badly work, the third not at all.

Comment: Oh ... hum ... u **just** mean "i want the slideshow to start automatically" ? That doesn't look like a QGIS problem ... perhaps there's a given parameter  (in the url) that can control this feature ...

Comment: Yes, you catched the issue; the problem is in the conversion of character |. I apologize for my answer's delay

Comment: U already said that ... So what is the final solution u found ? Thanks for sharing.

Comment: No solution so far